# Drawing an array of images on canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I want to draw an array of images on canvas. Here is my code without array:

```
var monsterReady1 = false;
var monsterImage1 = new Image();
monsterImage1.onload = function () {
    monsterReady1 = true;
};
monsterImage1.src = "fruit1.png";

var monster1 = {x: 0, y: 0};

var monsterXY1 = function () {
    monster1.x = (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 50));
    monster1.y = (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 50));
};

var render = function()
{
    if (monsterReady1) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage1, monster1.x, monster1.y);
    }
};
```

And this is the code I tried to use an array with, but it doesn't work:

```
var fruits = ["fruit1.png", "fruit2.png", "fruit3.png", "fruit4.png"];

for (var i = 1; i <= fruits.length; i++) {
    var monsterReady1 = false;
    var monsterImage1 = new Image();
    monsterImage1.onload = function () {
        monsterReady1 = true;
    };
    monsterImage1.src = fruits[i];
}
```

Comment: There are many examples of preloading an array of images before using them here on SO and elsewhere.  Here's one example: https://gist.github.com/m1erickson/1dbeeae071e986ddc45c

Comment: Yup, as markE said.. Also, using var i = 1 you will always skip your array element [0], won't you?